# Numpy product of 2d array and a long 1d array, result should be a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two arrays, a and b, with shapes; (3, 3) and (1000,). How do I multiply them to get an array with shape (3, 3, 1000)?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.linspace(1, 1000, 1000)

c = a * b # does not work
c = np.outer(a, b) # does not work
c = np.outer(a, b[None,] # nope
```

I have tried a lot of things, too many to remember them all.

I have also googled (and searched on SO) but to no avail.

Comment: `np.outer` docs should be clear that it is meant for 1d inputs.  However `np.outer(a,b).reshape(3,3,1000)` might just do the trick.  That reverses the flattening of `a` that `outer` talks about.

Comment: Interesting. Though I don't understand how .reshape(..) would change anything. np.outer(..) raises an exception, how would accessing a member method of the return value change that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `numpy.einsum`:

```
c = np.einsum("ij,k->ijk", a, b)
```

Output:

```
c.shape
# (3, 3, 1000)
```

Comment: +1 I am accepting this answer as it is the best one for my application. After reading about einsum I think this can actually do more things I need as well at the same time, and more efficiently.. Thanks a lot!. (bousof's answer is not bad either, I just like this one better..).

Comment: einsum is a beautiful function I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiplication by reshaping your arrays:

```
M,N = a.shape
B = b.size
c = a.reshape(M,N,1) * b.reshape(1,1,B)
print(c.shape)
print(c[:,:,0])
print(c[:,:,B-1])
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
(3, 3, 1000)
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [7. 8. 9.]]
[[1000. 2000. 3000.]
 [4000. 5000. 6000.]
 [7000. 8000. 9000.]]
```

Comment: The `b` reshape is not needed; `broadcasting` takes care of that (automatic leading dimensions).  But there's no harm in explicitly adding those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The bottomline is:

- both arrays need to have the same number of axes and
- the sizes along each axis must be the same or one of them must be 1.

You can multiply and array with shape (3,3) only by another with shape (3,3), (3,1) or (1,3). There are other broadcasting rules. Read them.

Your shapes are (3,3) and (1000,). As you said, you need the final shape to be 3-dimensional. The `3` needs to match an axis with length 1. Same with the `1000`. So you can add axes to each to end up with shapes (3, 3, 1) and (1, 1, 1000):

```
c = a[:, :, np.newaxis]* b[np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
```

Comment: This does not give an array with dimensions (3,3,1000) but rather one with dimensions (1000, 3, 3). You would have to also transpose the result to get it in the shape (3,3,1000) if you do it this way.

I must admit that I like this solution much less than the first two by Chris and bousof.

Comment: Fixed it in the answer.